# Problems using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, email

I'm trying to set it up so people can email from within my application. I'm referencing this post to do this, but I'm getting these warnings on the build:
[image]

and then when I run it, it bugs:
[image]

I'm wondering if I've simply placed the code in the wrong area. Just so you know I have placed

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

in the header file.

Thanks for the help!

---

**EDIT 1**

It seems as if the problem lies within how my ViewController is setup. In fact all my UI code is in a separate object as shown below. This is making it difficult for me to understand which code goes where. Any advice?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks like your SpeakHereController isn't a UIViewController.

Therefore it can't find the methods for presenting and dismissing the modalViewController.
Also you need to implement the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`, add it to your viewcontroller.

Comment: I think this is it. Could you expand on this a bit? What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Well in your SpeakHereController.h it should look like:               @interface SpeakHereController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

Answer (score 8):

Add the `MessageUI` framework into your framework folder and 
import these classes in your viewController.h:-

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface *your controller* : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> 

@interface tempsend : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

//.m file code

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];  
picmail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picmail setSubject:@"Exporting DDT file"];

// Set up recipients
[picmail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithArray:aray_emailid]];

[picmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:picmail animated:YES];
[picmail release];
```

Regards,
Shyam

Answer (score -1):

Add **MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegae** to SpeakHereController.h file

And use

`[controlle presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];`

Instead of

`[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];`

Same for

`[controlle dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Instead of

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: What do you mean by 'Add MFMComposeViewControllerDelegate to SpeakHereController.h file'. Is that a method?

Comment: Its a delegate class contain default methods definitions.

Comment: Sorry but presentModalViewController is not a UIView method.