# Implementing the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate and add it to your viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email

I'm trying to setup the ability to email from within my application. My app is based on the SpeakHere example project which uses an object to run all it's UI:
[image]

This has made it very confusing for me as to how I need to set up MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, etc.

This is somewhat an extension of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755066/problems-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using [this example code.](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/)

Answer (score 0):

Complete sample code:

```
- (IBAction)email:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Sample Subject"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"Here is some main text in the email!" isHTML:NO];
        [mail setToRecipients:@[@"testingEmail@example.com"]];

        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
    }
}

#pragma mark - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"You sent the email.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"You saved a draft of this email");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"You cancelled sending this email.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed:  An error occurred when trying to compose this email");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"An error occurred when trying to compose this email");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```